# Extraer solo el mes y el año con datetime en python

Tags: python, date

Hola mi pregunta es simple y es básicamente el titulo de la pregunta, tengo de código esto pero solo me extrae el mes o el año pero no los 2 juntos

```
frijolito@Frijolito:~/Escritorio/Retail$ python
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> from datetime import date
>>> 
>>> date.today()
datetime.date(2019, 8, 27)
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 27, 2, 33, 54, 625797)
>>> year = date.today()
>>> year.year
2019
>>> year.month
8
```

la cosa es que me gustaría tener en una variable solamente el 2019 y el 8 no con el dia como se hace con el `date.today()` ya que necesito guardar algunas cosas en una base de datos por meses y no por días. Gracias de antemano <3

Answer (score 2):

Si te sirve almacenarlas como texto también podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now()
year_month = date.strftime('%Y %m')

In[6]: year_month 
Out[6]: '2019 08'
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo como tú lo has hecho, usando los atributos que te ofrece la librería datetime **month** y **year**  te falta luego ponerlos en una lista, así:

```
import datetime

ano = datetime.datetime.today().year
mes = datetime.datetime.today().month
fecha = [ano, mes]

In[77]: fecha
Out[77]: [2019, 8]
```

No hay una función que extraiga el mes y el año exclusivamente.

Answer (score 0):

Estrictamente Python no permite lo que buscas. Un 'atajo' es:

```py
In [5]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                              
In [6]: nuevo = pd.Period(date.today().isoformat(),'M')                                                                                 
In [7]: nuevo                                                                                                                            
Out[7]: Period('2019-08', 'M')
In [8]: nuevo.year                                                                                                                       
Out[8]: 2019
In [9]: nuevo.month                                                                                                                      
Out[9]: 8

#-el atributo 'day' sigue existiendo, pero no es el adecuado.
In [10]: nuevo.day                                                                                                                        
Out[10]: 31
```